# Normalize x-axis to 0 to 1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
from scipy.stats import norm  

p=0.7
n=30
X=np.arange(0,n+1,1)
plist=stats.binom.pmf(X,n,p)
x_new = np.linspace(0, n, 300)
a_BSpline = make_interp_spline(X, plist)
y_new = a_BSpline(x_new)
plt.plot(x_new,y_new,label="Binom destribution p=0.5 n=5",linestyle='--')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)

plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.yscale("log")
plt.ylabel('(log10)Y')
plt.show()
```

I try many different code but it don't work, really reed some help. or can anyone give me some website I can look into please.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you're looking for, I think you can do that:

```
def standardize(x):
    return (x - np.mean(x)) / np.std(x)
```

and of course you'll need this too:

```
def unstandardize(x, x_ref):
    return x * np.std(l_ref) + np.mean(l_ref)
```

Where x_ref is your inital x before the standardize function.